# TableView cells disappearing when tapped / reloadData not changing cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I am having two problems with my TableView; the first is that whenever a cell is tapped, it disappears. The content view of the cell fades away and leaves a gap between the upper and lower cells. Nothing in my didSelect manipulates the content view.

The second issue is that reloadData doesn't actually update the TableView's data. My TableView is supposed to represent a calendar, and whenever the next or previous day buttons are called (`nextDay()` and `prevDay()` in the code below), the `displayDay` int is changed and `tableView.reloadData()` is called. `cellForRowAt` relies on `displayDay` to determine which day's event should be displayed in the cell, so in theory changing `displayDay` changes the content of the cells. However, what happens instead is that whenever the next or previous day buttons are pressed, the content of the cells does not change at all (ie, it still displays the first day's events). The only thing that changes is if the first day has fewer events than the second day, for example if the first day has 3 events and the second day 5, the table view will display the second day's last 2 events at the bottom of the first day's events. My code is below

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ScheduleTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var schedule: [DayItem]
    var displayDay: Int
    var numDays: Int?
    @IBOutlet weak var prevDayButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var nextDayButton: UIBarButtonItem!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
        //schedule = scrapeSchedule()
//        let add = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: nil)//action: #selector(addTapped))
//        navigationController!.toolbarItems = [add]
        let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:)))
        rightSwipe.direction = .right
        view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:)))
        leftSwipe.direction = .left
        view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.displayDay = 0
        self.schedule = [DayItem]()
        self.numDays = 0
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        refresh(self)
    }

    @objc func handleSwipes(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.direction == .right {
            if prevDayButton.isEnabled {
                prevDay(self)
            } else {
                dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        } else if sender.direction == .left {
            if nextDayButton.isEnabled {
                nextDay(self)
            }
        }
    }

    func reloadData() {
        tableView.reloadData()
        if schedule.count != 0 {
            self.navigationItem.title = self.schedule[self.displayDay].day
        }
    }

    func configureDayButtons() {
        if schedule.count == 0 {
            prevDayButton.isEnabled = false
            nextDayButton.isEnabled = false
        } else {
            prevDayButton.isEnabled = true
            nextDayButton.isEnabled = true

            if displayDay == 0 {
                prevDayButton.isEnabled = false
            }

            if displayDay == numDays! - 1 {
                nextDayButton.isEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func prevDay(_ sender: Any) {
        if displayDay != 0 {
            displayDay -= 1
            configureDayButtons()
            reloadData()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func nextDay(_ sender: Any) {
        if displayDay != numDays! - 1 {
            displayDay += 1
            configureDayButtons()
            reloadData()
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        if schedule.count != 0 {
            return schedule[displayDay].events.count
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let dayItem = schedule[displayDay]
        print("display day = \(displayDay)")
        let eventItem = dayItem.events[indexPath.row]
        let identifier = eventItem.identifier
        let eventOrTimeText = eventItem.event

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)
        let label = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as! UILabel
        label.text = eventOrTimeText
        if identifier == "event" || identifier == "eventDDI" {
            label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        } else if identifier == "time" || identifier == "location" {
           label.sizeToFit()
        }

        return UITableViewCell()

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        if schedule[displayDay].events[indexPath.row].information != nil {
            let message = schedule[displayDay].events[indexPath.row].information
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: schedule[displayDay].events[indexPath.row].event, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(action)
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func close(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func refresh(_ sender: Any) {
        scrapeSchedule { schedule in
            self.schedule = schedule!
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.reloadData()
                self.numDays = self.schedule.count
                self.configureDayButtons()
            }
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       // if schedule.
        if schedule.count != 0 {
            let event = schedule[displayDay].events[indexPath.row]
            if event.identifier == "time" && event.event.count > 51 {
                return 75
            } else if event.identifier == "time" && event.event.count > 31 {
                let additionalChars = event.event.count - 31
                var quotient: Float = Float(additionalChars) / 20.0
                quotient = quotient.rounded(.up)
                return CGFloat(quotient * 14 + 40)
            }
        }
        return 34
    }

    func scrapeSchedule(completion: @escaping ([DayItem]?) -> Void) {
        var schedule = [DayItem]()
        URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
        Alamofire.request("my api that functions correctly", method: .get).validate().responseData { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                do {
                    let json = try JSON(data: data)
                    for (index,day):(String, JSON) in json {
                        schedule.append(self.organizeScheduleJSON(dayJSON: day))
                    }
                    completion(schedule)
                } catch {
                    completion(nil)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }

    func organizeScheduleJSON(dayJSON: JSON) -> DayItem {
        var events = [EventItem]()
        for (index,event):(String, JSON) in dayJSON["eventTimes"] {
            if event["information"] != nil {
                events.append(EventItem(event: event["event"].string!, identifier: "eventDDI", information: event["information"].string!))
            } else {
                events.append(EventItem(event: event["event"].string!, identifier: "event"))
            }
            if event["location"] != nil {
                events.append(EventItem(event: event["location"].string!, identifier: "location"))
            }
            if event["times"] != nil {
                var timeArray = event["times"].arrayValue.map({$0.stringValue})
                for time in timeArray {
                    events.append(EventItem(event: time, identifier: "time"))
                }
            }
        }
        return DayItem(day: dayJSON["day"].string!, events: events)

    }
}
```

Comment: Your `cellForRow(at:)` doesn't look right.  It always `return UITableViewCell()` rather than the `cell` you configured.

Comment: That solved it...don't know how I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `cellForRow(at:)` is always returning an empty `UITableViewCell` rather than your configured `cell` object.

Replace `return UITableViewCell()` with `return cell`